# Solr highlighting - terms with umlaut not found/not highlighted

Tags: solr, query-parser

I am playing with 7.2 version of solr. I've uploaded a nice collection of texts in German language and trying to query and highlight a few queries.

If I fire this query with hightlight:

http://localhost:8983/solr/trans/select?q=trans:Zeit&hl=true&hl.fl=trans&hl.q=Kundigung&hl.snippets=3&wt=xml&rows=1

I get a nice text back:

```
<response>
    <lst name="responseHeader">
        <bool name="zkConnected">true</bool>
        <int name="status">0</int>
        <int name="QTime">10</int>
        <lst name="params">
            <str name="hl.snippets">3</str>
            <str name="q">trans:Zeit</str>
            <str name="hl">true</str>
            <str name="hl.q">Kundigung</str>
            <str name="hl.fl">trans</str>
            <str name="rows">1</str>
            <str name="wt">xml</str>
        </lst>
    </lst>
    <result name="response" numFound="418" start="0" maxScore="1.6969817">
        <doc>
            <str name="id">x</str>
            <str name="trans">... Zeit  ...</str>
            <date name="t">2018-03-01T14:32:29.400Z</date>
            <int name="l">2305</int>
            <long name="_version_">1594374122229465088</long>
        </doc>
    </result>
    <lst name="highlighting">
        <lst name="x">
            <arr name="trans">
                <str> ... <em>Kündigung</em> ... </str>
                <str> ... <em>Kündigung</em> ... </str>
            </arr>
        </lst>
    </lst>
</response>
```

However, if I supply the `Kündigung` as highlight text, I get no answers, as the text/query parser replaced all the `ü` characters with `u`.

I have a feeling that I need to supply the correct qparser. How should I specify it? It seems to me that the collection was build with and queried with the default `LuceneQParser` parser. How can I supply this parser in the url above?

**UPDATE:**

`http://localhost:8983/solr/trans/schema/fields/trans` returns

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":0},
  "field":{
    "name":"trans",
    "type":"text_de",
    "indexed":true,
    "stored":true}}
```

**Update 2**: So I've looked at the managed-schema of my solr installation/collection schema configuration and found the following:

```
  <fieldType name="text_de" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer>
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" format="snowball" words="lang/stopwords_de.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.GermanNormalizationFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.GermanLightStemFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
```

the way I interpret the information is that since query and index parts are omited, the above code is meant to be the same for both query and index. Which... does not show any misconfiguration issues similar to [the answer 2 below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49276093/solr-highlighting-terms-with-umlaut-not-found-not-highlighted/49314056#49314056)...

I rememberred though, adding the field `trans` with type `text_de`:

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-type:application/json' --data-binary '{
"add-field":{
     "name":"trans",
     "type":"text_de",
     "stored":true,
     "indexed":true}
}' http://localhost:8983/solr/trans/schema
```

I've deleted all the documents using

```
curl http://localhost:8983/solr/trans/update?commit=true -d "<delete><query>*:*<
/query></delete>"
```

and then reinserting them again:

```
curl  -X POST http://localhost:8983/solr/trans/update?commit=true -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d @all.json
```

Is it the correct way to "rebuild" the indexes in solr?

**UPDATE 3:** The Charset settings of the standart JAVA installation were not set to UTF-8:

```
C:\tmp>java -classpath . Hello
Cp1252
Cp1252
windows-1252

C:\tmp>cat Hello.java
public class Hello {
 public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{
  // not crossplateform safe
  System.out.println(System.getProperty("file.encoding"));
  // jdk1.4
  System.out.println(
     new java.io.OutputStreamWriter(
        new java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream()).getEncoding()
     );
  // jdk1.5
  System.out.println(java.nio.charset.Charset.defaultCharset().name());
  }
}
```

**UPDATE 4**: Restarted the solr with UTF8 settings:

```
bin\solr.cmd start -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -c -p 8983 -s example/cloud/node1/solr
bin\solr.cmd start -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -c -p 7574 -s example/cloud/node2/solr -z localhost:9983
```

Checked the JVM settings:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/#/~java-properties



file.​encoding    UTF8
file.​encoding.​pkg    sun.io
```

reinserted the docs. No change: `http://localhost:8983/solr/trans/select?q=trans:Zeit&hl=true&hl.fl=trans&hl.q=Kundigung&hl.qparser=lucene&hl.snippets=3&rows=1&wt=xml` gives:

```
<lst name="highlighting">
    <lst name="32e42caa-313d-45ed-8095-52f2dd6861a1">
        <arr name="trans">
            <str> ... <em>Kündigung</em> ...</str>
            <str> ... <em>Kündigung</em> ...</str>
        </arr>
    </lst>
</lst>
```

`http://localhost:8983/solr/trans/select?q=trans:Zeit&hl=true&hl.fl=trans&hl.q=K%C3%BCndigung&hl.qparser=lucene&hl.snippets=3&rows=1&wt=xml` gives:

```
<lst name="highlighting">
    <lst name="32e42caa-313d-45ed-8095-52f2dd6861a1"/>
</lst>
```

`uchardet all.json` (`file -bi all.json`) reports `UTF-8`

Running from the ubuntu subsystem under windows:

```
$ export LC_ALL='en_US.UTF-8'
$ export LC_CTYPE='en_US.UTF-8'
$ curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://localhost:8983/solr/trans/query?hl=true\&hl.fl=trans\&fl=id -d '
{
  "query" : "trans:Kündigung",
  "limit" : "1", params: {"hl.q":"Kündigung"}
}'
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "zkConnected":true,
    "status":0,
    "QTime":21,
    "params":{
      "hl":"true",
      "fl":"id",
      "json":"\n{\n  \"query\" : \"trans:Kündigung\",\n  \"limit\" : \"1\", params: {\"hl.q\":\"Kündigung\"}\n}",
      "hl.fl":"trans"}},
  "response":{"numFound":124,"start":0,"maxScore":4.3724422,"docs":[
      {
        "id":"b952b811-3711-4bb1-ae3d-e8c8725dcfe7"}]
  },
  "highlighting":{
    "b952b811-3711-4bb1-ae3d-e8c8725dcfe7":{}}}
$ curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://localhost:8983/solr/trans/query?hl=true\&hl.fl=trans\&fl=id -d '
{
  "query" : "trans:Kündigung",
  "limit" : "1", params: {"hl.q":"Kundigung"}
}'
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "zkConnected":true,
    "status":0,
    "QTime":18,
    "params":{
      "hl":"true",
      "fl":"id",
      "json":"\n{\n  \"query\" : \"trans:Kündigung\",\n  \"limit\" : \"1\", params: {\"hl.q\":\"Kundigung\"}\n}",
      "hl.fl":"trans"}},
  "response":{"numFound":124,"start":0,"maxScore":4.3724422,"docs":[
      {
        "id":"b952b811-3711-4bb1-ae3d-e8c8725dcfe7"}]
  },
  "highlighting":{
    "b952b811-3711-4bb1-ae3d-e8c8725dcfe7":{
      "trans":[" ... <em>Kündigung</em> ..."]}}}
```

**UPDATE 5** Without supplying `hl.q` (`http://localhost:8983/solr/trans/select?q=trans:Kundigung&hl=true&hl.fl=trans&hl.qparser=lucene&hl.snippets=3&rows=1&wt=xml` or `http://localhost:8983/solr/trans/select?q=trans:K%C3%BCndigung&hl=true&hl.fl=trans&hl.qparser=lucene&hl.snippets=3&rows=1&wt=xml`):

```
<lst name="highlighting">
    <lst name="b952b811-3711-4bb1-ae3d-e8c8725dcfe7">
        <arr name="trans">
            <str> ... <em>Kündigung</em> ... </str>
            <str> ... <em>Kündigung</em> ... </str>
            <str> ... <em>Kündigung</em> ... </str>
        </arr>
    </lst>
</lst>
```

in this case, the `hl.q` took the highlighting terms from the query itself, and did a superb job..

Comment: How does it behave without explicitly setting hl.q?

Comment: Without `hl.q`, the highlighting returns results correctly...

Comment: It looks like you are running multiple instances with zookeeper. Does the problem also appear with a single core collection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your analyzer chain too. I get the same behaviour as you described, when I misconfigure the chain this way:

```
  <fieldType name="text_de" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer type="query">
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" format="snowball" words="lang/stopwords_de.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="index">
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" format="snowball" words="lang/stopwords_de.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.GermanNormalizationFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.GermanLightStemFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
```

The  `GermanNormalizationFilterFactory`  and  `GermanLightStemFilterFactory` both replaces umlauts.

Comment: Thanks for the infos on the configuration side. Does that mean that `hl.qparser` is not an option to adress the situation of misconfiguration? I thought it should be possible to use a different query parser to "replace/rewrite" the query?

Comment: As far as I understand the process no matter what query parser you set, the analyzer configuration is crucial. The query parser will not do german normalisation filtering or stemming on its own. So query and index analysis have to suit each other.

Comment: Looks like the analyzer was set correctly.. Any other comments?

Answer (score 2):

Could be a problem with your JVM's encoding. What about -Dfile.encoding=UTF8? Check LC_ALL and LC_CTYPE too. Should be UTF-8.

What field type is the trans field? I even indexed german text with text_en and do not have any problems with Umlauts in highlighting or search and I use the LuceneQParser too.

How looks the response when you query via Solr Admin UI (http://localhost:8983/solr/#/trans/query) and hl checkbox activated?

Comment: (1) W.r.t. the encoding, I'll let you know tomorrow. I do not think that it is the UTF8 related issue, since I am able to "search" for UTF8 chars (Kündigung is replaced in search, but not in highlighting).

(2) Currently I have the parse set to default. How can I set the parse explicitely to "LuceneQParser" via url?

(3) If I go through Solr Admin UI and activate the Checkbox, then "&hl=on" is added to the url. In my case it is "&hl=true". I've tested both urls (with "&hl=on" and with "&hl=true", the result is the same)

Comment: in the above comment I mean `hl.qparser`, when I talk about the parser

Comment: (2) hl.qparser=lucene

Comment: nice! do you know other parsers that are available?

Comment: setting the parser to `lucene` did not solve the problem

Answer (score 1):

What you need to specify is the attribute, for which the highlighting is done. Similar to `q=trans:Zeit`, where you specified `trans` as an attribute, you need to specify `hl.q` to be `hl.q=trans:Kündigung`. Your request then becomes:

[http://localhost:8983/solr/trans/select?q=trans:Zeit&hl=true&hl.fl=trans&hl.q=trans:Kündigung&hl.snippets=3&wt=xml&rows=1](http://localhost:8983/solr/trans/select?q=trans:Zeit&hl=true&hl.fl=trans&hl.q=trans:K%C3%BCndigung&hl.snippets=3&wt=xml&rows=1)

This answer was humbly presented by David Smiley, Stefan Matheis, and Erick Erickson, solr community and support. This is the post on their behalf.

Comment: Congratulation, Arthur. It's so simple ;-)

Comment: Thanks mate. What do you think, are we ready to select one of these posts as "answered"?

Comment: Of course. Thanks to David Smiley, Stefan Matheis, and Erick Erickson.

Comment: Which answer would you recommend to choose as the final one?

Comment: Thanks Arthur, but I would have accepted your answer. The missing field name in hl.q caused the trouble. Sorry for responding so late.